# need to persist cookies in Ruby ala Python's 'requests' library Session() object

Tags: python, ruby, python-requests, rest-client, httparty

So I have a Python script that's working successfully to call a series of URLs with get and post requests, which eventually results in an authentication token I can use for further work. The Python script uses the `requests` library, and starts things off with a `Session` object like so:

```
session = requests.Session()
initial_auth = session.request('GET', login_url)
step_2_url = do_stuff_to_initial_auth()
intermediate_token = session.request('POST', step_2_url)
step_3_url = do_stuff_to_intermediate_token()
final_auth = session.request('GET', step_3_url)
```

I'm trying to port the script to Ruby, but the script fails at the final step -- the remote service returns some 'Page Expired' html rather than the success page received by the Python script. Digging deeper, I'm seeing that there's a fair amount of cookie state passed from step to step, and that the Python requests.Session object is handling the cookie state automagically behind the scenes.

I'm looking at `httparty` and `rest-client` for equivalent magic functionality. I'm seeing references to cookiejars and Resources, but using a cookiejar so far to set cookies isn't working for me.

Is there a way in the Ruby ecosystem to automagically handle cookies across multiple requests like Python's requests.Session?

Thanks ~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize). For example:

```
mechanize  = Mechanize.new
page       = mechanize.get(url)
other_page = mechanize.get(other_url)
```

This persists cookies across requests.